# Time change when hosting WCF service in internet IIS

Tags: wcf

I was work in WCF service in local IIS and SQL server in internet hosting

the time was return fine, but when I host WCF Service in internet IIS return time as  (UTC -9)

how i can fix this problem

Note:
the data return as Datatable

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qniSu.jpg)

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset and store the dates with the timezone they're supposed to be in.

Comment: this work but will make another problem if  user use it in UK and other one in USA